# Make a sprite 'destruction' effect in GIMP

Tags: gimp, filter, sprite

I need to apply a destruction effect to my game sprites when they are damaged so that they seem they are getting more destroyed.

I'm using GIMP for editing and designing, I tried before adding an HSV noise effect to the image I'm working on, this gave the sprite the impression that is destroyed but not that much, it wasn't really a good effect.

So is there any other method to implement that in GIMP ?

Comment: Incremental fade to black or gray or even transparent seem an obvious choice (although pretty basic). It seems you are asking for an idea about how to show something in your game. It would be better to decide how you want to portray the 'destruction' and then try and implement that. Then if you run into difficulty implementing that come back and ask a question about a specific problem you are having with that implementation. That way, someone can give a specific answer to that problem. That is how this site is designed to work.

Comment: This question is  a bit broad. Any chance you could show us what you tried and say what is wrong with it? It's really hard to answer graphics questions without seeing anything.

Comment: @BillyKerr, the problem of HSV noise effect that I've tried is that it adds unwanted colors to the sprite, it becomes then just like a rainbow-coloured sprite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill a layer above your artwork with any colour you want. Set the layer mode to Dissolve. Move the opacity slider from 0 towards 100 for more noise.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! That's useful, and I think it will be better to use a dark shade of gray instead of black